# Amazon Web Service S3 bucket is not secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an AWS S3 bucket and uploaded my application.  When I enter the endpoint into a browser url, the url alerts me to the fact that the site is not secure.  When I look at the console.log, I see the following warning:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context.

Currently, I reference my endpoint as

> http://.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

This was generated by AWS when I created my domain in the bucket.
I tried entering

> https://.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

But this gave me a url not found error page.

Where can I find the setting so I can reference my site with https instead of http?

Thanks.

Comment: Neither endpoint includes the S3 bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets do not support HTTPS for web hosting. But you can put CloudFront in front of your bucket for this.

https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/setup-aws-s3-static-website-hosting-using-ssl-acm-34d41d32e394

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security needs, you can also change settings in s3. Go to your s3 bucket from AWS console. Click on permissions, then public access settings. You could set the values to the following:

Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)
False
Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)
False
Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)
True
Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies (Recommended)
False

Again, this might not suit your security needs, but it will allow that URL to work.